# Get correct number of rows of a subset of a data.table for the sample() function

Tags: r, data.table

I want to assign random values to a subset of the rows in a `data.table`.

I have tried:

`data[age>=18]$edu.hs <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), .N ,replace=TRUE)`

But I obtain an

> invalid 'size' argument

error

Comment: Hi! Given how you specified your code, I would like to encourage you to work through the nice `data.table` vignettes, [Intro](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) and [how to add and update columns by reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) (like in your question). Also, for future questions, please provide tiny toy data (something like Ronak did) Good luck with your `data.table` coding!

Answer (score 2):

`.N` is valid only when you are using it inside `data.table`. Try :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

set.seed(12343)
data[age>=18, edu.hs := sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), .N,replace=TRUE)]
data

#   age edu.hs
#1:  25  FALSE
#2:  31   TRUE
#3:  10     NA
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(age = c(25, 31, 10))
```

Comment: You can use `.N` instead of `sum(age >= 18)` because `.N` is the number of rows in the data *satisfying* i.